# MySQL + LOAD DATA INFILE + variable path

Tags: mysql

Below is my code code and is wrong for MySQL. 
@Path not be allowed variable with syntax "LOAD DATA INFILE" and I don't know exactly path + filename.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

```
SET @Path = CONCAT(sysf_Get_Options('DRIVE'),sysf_Get_Options('PATH_SAP_FILE'),'277.txt');

LOAD DATA INFILE @Path
  INTO TABLE SAP_TMP 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  (@var1)
  SET txt = SP_INSERT_ROW_CONTRACTS(@var1)
;
```

Answer (score 5):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html says:

> The file name must be given as a literal string.

So you can't use a variable for the path. You have to code a literal, quoted string into the statement *before* it is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround we used was to copy the source file into a temporary file and to reference the temporary file in the INFILE line.
Something like: (for windows, for Linux it's not so different)

```
copy /Y C:/path_to_file/277.txt C:/temp/tempData.txt
```

and then

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/temp/tempData.txt'
```

That way you can hardcode the path in the sql script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) + [php](/questions/tagged/php)

```js
var Upload = function (file) {
  this.file = file;
};

$("#csvfile").on("change", function (e) {
  var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
  var upload = new Upload(file);
  upload.doUpload();
});


Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {

  // Retrieve the FileList object from the referenced element ID
  var myFileList = document.getElementById('csvfile').files;

  // Grab the first File Object from the FileList
  var myFile = myFileList[0];

  // Set some variables containing the three attributes of the file
  var myFileName = myFile.name;
  var myFileSize = myFile.size;
  var myFileType = myFile.type;

  // Alert the information we just gathered
  alert("FileName: " + myFileName + "- FileSize: " + myFileSize + " - FileType: " + myFileType);

  // Let's upload the complete file object
  // Open Our formData Object
  var formData = new FormData();

  // Append our file to the formData object
  // Notice the first argument "file" and keep it in mind
  formData.append('my_uploaded_file', myFile);

  // Create our XMLHttpRequest Object
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Open our connection using the POST method
  xhr.open("POST", 'uploadcsv.php');

  // Send the file
  xhr.send(formData);


  var fileFullpath="'C:\\\\"+ myFileName + "'";
  var query = "LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE " + fileFullpath + " INTO TABLE tb_Name CHARACTER SET cp1256 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4);";

   
  //INSERT file into DB
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'insertData.php',
    async:false, //to make sure all data inserted
    data:{'data':query},
    success: function(data){
      if(data){
        $("#status").append("<br />Data added successfuly");
      }else{
        $("#status").append("<br />Something went wrong, can't edit the row. ");
      }
    }
  });
   
   
   
  //Then delete uploaded file after INSERT
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'deletecsv.php',
    data: {'file' : myFileName },
    success: function (response) {
      alert("deleted");
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("can't delete file csv");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" onsubmit="return submitForm();"> 
  Upload CSV file :
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="csvfile" id="csvfile" />
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

and the [php](/questions/tagged/php) files:
uploadcsv.php

```
//uploadcsv
$fileName = $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['type'];
$fileTemppath = $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$fileError = $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['error'];
//$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
//print_r ($fileContent);

if($fileError == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    //Processes your file here
    move_uploaded_file($fileTemppath, "C:/" . $fileName);
}else{
   switch($fileError){
     case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:   
          $message = 'Error uploading file that exceeds allowed size.';
          break;
     case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:  
          $message = 'Error uploading file that exceeds allowed size.';
          break;
     case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:    
          $message = 'Error: do not finish? The action of uploading the file.';
          break;
     case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:    
          $message = 'Error: No file was uploaded.';
          break;
     case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
          $message = 'Error: Server not configured for file upload.';
          break;
     case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
          $message= 'Error: Possible failure to save file.';
          break;
     case  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
          $message = 'Error: File upload not completed.';
          break;
     default: $message = 'Error: File upload not completed.';
              break;
    }
      echo json_encode(array(
               'error' => true,
               'message' => $message
            ));
}
```

insertData.php:

```
//insertData
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    @mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die ("error in host connection");
    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("error in db connection");

$thedata = $_POST['data'];

$result=mysql_query($thedata);
if(isset($result)) {echo "YES";} else {echo "NO";}
```

and last file will be deletecsv.php

```
//deletecsv
$fileName = $_POST['file'];
unlink("C:/" . $fileName);
```

Hope it help